# Current in all earth pins

Tags: electrical, grounding

We started feeling a very light electrical shock when touching certain devices connected to the house’s electrical circuit. I tested it and noticed there was some voltage in all earth pins, which  disappeared when we disconnected entirely the induction cooktop from the electrical network.

Can this be caused only by a faulty cooktop?

Additional clarifications:

- We tested the ground circuit on several pins and cables with a multimeter and an electrical tester screwdriver, and invariably there was voltage.
- The RCDs are on the breaker panel. Pushing the test button make it break.
- Power is 3-phase.
- I checked the voltage of various outlets, they all indicated around 240V +- 5V (I’m in EU).

[image: Breaker panel and RCDs]

Comment: When you say "current" do you mean "voltage" or are you testing with a clamp meter? Where is the RCD or RCDs? Can you [edit] to add a pic of your consumer unit / breaker panel?  Yes, there are faults which can cause this.  Also does your utility provide 2- or 3-phase power? Can you check voltage of various sockets around the house, or the 3 phases in some way?  We're looking for "not equal".

Comment: EMF goes everywhere. Means your Inductive coils radiate EMF into ground wire. Bad EMF filters

Comment: Electric shock (static) can also be caused if you are getting charged because you are insulated from the floor.  Because you are wearing better insulated slippers/shoes.  And certain clothes such as silk and nylon will produce more static.  Maybe its a combination of this and EMF (as mentioned above)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I’ve added clarifications and corrected the wrong use of "current".

Comment: Re: "We tested the ground circuit on several pins and cables with a multimeter and an electrical tester screwdriver, and invariably there was voltage."
Where were the two multimeter probes attached (that is, voltage relative to what?)?

Comment: One was connected to ground, the other to neutral of the same outlet. The results were consistent with what we were observing with the electrical tester screwdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tingle or buzz you feel is *voltage* not current.  You should **never** feel this on the earth/ground.  I suspect you have a disconnected ground which implies dodgy house wiring. *But also* there could be issues with the cooker.  Fixing one of these issues could easily leave the other in a dangerous state.  Therefore get a professional to inspect the whole house.

Comment: The cooker may have a low current, high voltage leak. Most switch mode power supplies have such leaks - and they are not dangerous, but you may feel them if the appliance is unearthed.

Comment: There was indeed no ground, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can be caused by faulty earthing.

Appliances are allowed to leak a very small current to Earth.  This usually happens in the filters on switch mode power supplies, which are used in many appliances nowadays.

If your supply is correctly earthed, you shouldn't ever feel this leakage.  If the earth has been disconnected, then a significant voltage can build up on any Class I appliances; ones with an earthed metal chassis.